# Creating separate date and time columns in R

Tags: r, date, time

So I have a combined date and time column that looks like the following attached here (let us call this column Date and Time).

| Date and Time |
| --- |
| 10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM |
| 9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM |
| 9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM |
| 8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM |

I want to separate the date and time into two separate entries, so have one column for date and one column for time. How would I go about doing this in R?

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 10/28/2023 | 11:00:00 PM |
| 9/22/2023 | 11:47:00 AM |
| 9/22/2023 | 11:47:00 AM |
| 8/24/2023 | 11:58:00 AM |

To give some more insight, Date and Time is represented as a character. I essentially want to separate this into two columns for interpretability and readability. I may want to filter records based on a specific date range, which is easier when date and time are separate. It is also more straightforward to perform arithmetic operations on time intervals when the date and time are distinct.

The code I have tried is here, but I am fairly introductory to R, so the code didn't work out. I was essentially trying to update the Date and Time column to only include the time and create a separate date column which extracts the date from the combined date and time.

I think it would be better, however, to retain the combined column and just make two separate columns.

```
# create a new column called Date
# where we extract the date from Time
# update Time format to only include the time
data <- data %>% 
mutate(`Time` = strptime(`Time`, format = "%I:%M:%S %p"),
`Date` = as.Date(`Time`),
`Time` = format(`Time`, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: @r2evans The data is protected, so I can't include that here.

Comment: I understand, many times questions are based on proprietary data, which is perfectly fine. However, there are two things here: (1) you don't have to give us _actual_ data, just data that is representative enough to your real data that we can get the job done; and (2) I am not going to spend time **transcribing** data into something usable. So if you cannot spend the time to come up with reasonable, representative, sample data, then I think you're asking a lot of us to work from an image of your data and assume we will type everything in ourselves.

Comment: I'll add in the data now as a text

Comment: Additionally, what research have you done? What code have you tried? Also, why do you need to split this into date and time? There are a lot of questions about spitting text based on patterns, converting to true timestamps and then extract "time-of-day" out of the `POSIXt`-class values, etc.

Comment: @cake2244, it's also going to be important to understand how the data is currently stored.  Is the date/time field above a character vector or a datetime field in R?

Comment: @cake2244, can you also help us understand your MOTIVATION for splitting the data into two fields?  Why do you want the date separated from the time?  I suspect you're better keeping the data as a single field, but may not know how to go about a better solution to your true problem.  However, this really depends on the motivation behind your desire to split the variable into two separate variables.

Comment: cake2244, the question is in a much better state, thank you for making those edits! (I still recommend going back to previous questions and accepting answers.)

Comment: Thanks! If anyone has any solution for this question, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @cake2244, I just added my answer.  Based on your revised question, I still think you are better off just learning/understanding how datetimes work in R and taking advantage of the datetime fields to arithmetically manipulate your date/time fields and to query/filter data based on your date times.  When you start separating the date from the times, it get tricky and ugly filtering data if you want to filter by both some time dimension and a date dimension, and I think you are much better off using a datetime field.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you don't separate the date and time into separate fields.  Instead, you should try to learn how datetime fields work and how you can use them to your advantage.  The concerns, you have about arithmetic manipulation of dates/times and filtering of dates and times is not a strong argument, in my opinion, for splitting out the date and time, because R, along with the tidyverse and lubridate packages handles all this very easily.  In the code that follows, I set up a character vector of dates, convert this into a datetime field and then show you how easy it is to manipulate the dates in datetime format, specifically addressing your concerns over mathematical manipulation of the dates/times and querying dates/times.

```
# Load the tidyvere and lubridate packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
        
# Create a character vector of "dates and times."
my_df <- data.frame(mydate = c("10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM", 
                                "9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM", 
                                "9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM", 
                                "8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM"))
        
# Convert to datetime format
(my_df2 <- my_df %>% 
    mutate(mydate_dt = as_datetime(mydate, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")))    

                      mydate           mydate_dt
    1 10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM 2023-10-28 23:00:00
    2  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00
    3  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00
    4  8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM 2023-08-24 11:58:00    

# Query all records be between 08/20/2023 and 09/23/2023
(my_df2 %>% filter(
  between(mydate_dt, 
          as.Date("2023-08-20"), 
          as.Date("2023-09-23"))
  ))
                 mydate           mydate_dt
1 9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00
2 9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00
3 8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM 2023-08-24 11:58:00

    
# Add 4 hours to the time
(my_df2 %>% mutate(time_plus_three=mydate_dt+hours(4)))

                  mydate           mydate_dt     time_plus_three
1 10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM 2023-10-28 23:00:00 2023-10-29 03:00:00
2  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 2023-09-22 15:47:00
3  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 2023-09-22 15:47:00
4  8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM 2023-08-24 11:58:00 2023-08-24 15:58:00
    
# Add 3 days to the time
(my_df2 %>% mutate(time_plus_three=mydate_dt+days(3)))

                  mydate           mydate_dt     time_plus_three
1 10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM 2023-10-28 23:00:00 2023-10-31 23:00:00
2  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 2023-09-25 11:47:00
3  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 2023-09-25 11:47:00
4  8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM 2023-08-24 11:58:00 2023-08-27 11:58:00
    
#Display and date and time only in separate fields and formatted in different ways.
(my_df2 %>% mutate(
                  time_only = format(mydate_dt, "%I:%M:%S %p"),
                  date_only = format(mydate_dt, "%m/%d/%Y"),
                  time_24   = format(mydate_dt, "%T")
                  ))


                  mydate           mydate_dt   time_only  date_only  time_24
1 10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM 2023-10-28 23:00:00 11:00:00 PM 10/28/2023 23:00:00
2  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 11:47:00 AM 09/22/2023 11:47:00
3  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 11:47:00 AM 09/22/2023 11:47:00
4  8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM 2023-08-24 11:58:00 11:58:00 AM 08/24/2023 11:58:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
     Date.and.Time = c("10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM",
                       "9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM","9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM",
                       "8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM")
) |> mutate(dt = lubridate::mdy_hms(Date.and.Time),
            Date = lubridate::as_date(dt),
            Time = format(dt, format = "%H:%M:%S"),
            Time2 = hms::as_hms(dt))

           Date.and.Time                  dt       Date     Time    Time2
1 10/28/2023 11:00:00 PM 2023-10-28 23:00:00 2023-10-28 23:00:00 23:00:00
2  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 2023-09-22 11:47:00 11:47:00
3  9/22/2023 11:47:00 AM 2023-09-22 11:47:00 2023-09-22 11:47:00 11:47:00
4  8/24/2023 11:58:00 AM 2023-08-24 11:58:00 2023-08-24 11:58:00 11:58:00
```

A couple observations:

1. calculating on dates or datetimes will be easiest if you can make the date into the R data types Date or POSIXct (datetime) early on. Those will always appear in YYYY-MM-DD order -- any other order suggests your data is in a human-readable but not directly calculable form.
2. the formatted Time column here will be a pain to calculate on;
   Time2 will be more useful -- you can add an hour, compare two times, etc. If any calculations involve multiple days, `dt` is more useful still. In my own experience, separating date and time makes filtering and comparisons more complicated, but might be helpful in certain areas like visualization or reporting.